# Now do you create transaction in Neo4j 2.0?

Tags: java, scala, transactions, neo4j

Now do you create transaction in Neo4j 2.0 ? I tried dozens of ways and none of them worked.

Basically problem is that second and subsequent transactions are never successful. Perhaps I don't begin transactions properly. I don't know. I tried all possible combinations that I see in your unit-tests and also in `ExecutionEngine`.

Here is how I create transaction:

```
  private def withTransaction[T](f: => T): T = {
    // FIXME: Sometimes it returns PlaceboTransaction which causes TONS of issues
    val tx = db.beginTx
    try {
      val result = f
      tx.success()
      result
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable =>

        // If I don't check this I'll get NullPointerException in TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly()
        if (!tx.isInstanceOf[PlaceboTransaction])
          tx.failure()

        throw e
    } finally {

      // If I don't check this I'll get NullPointerException in TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly()
      if (!tx.isInstanceOf[PlaceboTransaction])
        tx.close()

    }
  }
```

It never works. Attempts to fetch any data/properties of Node cause following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.transaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.statement(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasLabel(NodeProxy.java:551)
    at GraphDBManager$$anonfun$findUsers$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphDBManager.scala:72)
    at GraphDBManager$$anonfun$findUsers$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphDBManager.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at GraphDBManager$$anonfun$findUsers$1.apply(GraphDBManager.scala:72)
    at GraphDBManager$$anonfun$findUsers$1.apply(GraphDBManager.scala:72)
    at GraphDBManager$.withTransaction(GraphDBManager.scala:38)
    at GraphDBManager$.findUsers(GraphDBManager.scala:71)
    at Test$.main(Test.scala:12)
    at Test.main(Test.scala)
```

I created sample project **[here](https://github.com/cppexpert/neo4j_2_bad_transactions)**.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a client code bug, Pull Request to the project in question here: https://github.com/cppexpert/neo4j_2_bad_transactions/pull/1

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I have one question though. Wouldn't it be more consistent from architecture design prospective to throw `NotInTransaction` exception in `ExecutionEngine.execute` instead of creating transaction inside it ?

Answer (score 2):

Well.. After hours of debugging I figured it out. I hope it's going to be fixed in final release.

Here is how problem function looks like

```
def findUsers: List[ObjectId] = {
  val query = engine.execute(s"MATCH (n:$label) RETURN n")
  val it = query.columnAs[Node]("n")

  withTransaction {
    val lst = it.toList
    val ret = for (node <- lst; if node.hasLabel(label)) yield new ObjectId(node.getProperty("id").asInstanceOf[String])
    ret
  }
}
```

Turned out `ExecutionEngine.execute` leaves transaction open that causes `beginTx()` in `withTransaction` return `PlaceboTransaction` instead of real transaction object. On the other hand I can't get rid of my transaction wrapper because `NodeProxy` surprisingly gets transaction object differently

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.transaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.statement(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasLabel(NodeProxy.java:551)
```

where it comes from

```
private KernelTransaction transaction()
{
    checkIfShutdown();
    KernelTransaction transaction = txManager.getKernelTransaction();
    if ( transaction == null )
    {
        throw new NotInTransactionException();
    }
    return transaction;
}
```

What's the difference between transaction from `getKernelTransaction` and object from TLS map I don't know.

Therefore fixed version of my function would be

```
def findUsers: List[ObjectId] = {
  val query = engine.execute(s"MATCH (n:$label) RETURN n")
  val it = query.columnAs[Node]("n")
  val lst = it.toList
  query.close()

  withTransaction {
    val ret = for (node <- lst; if node.hasLabel(label)) yield new ObjectId(node.getProperty("id").asInstanceOf[String])
    ret
  }
}
```

Which in my opinion not only ugly from design prospective but also give inconsistent data when I iterate through nodes in second transaction.